# How do I center the hint text within an EditText in Android?

Tags: android

I need to center the Hint text within an `EditText` in Android.  How do I do this?

Comment: Use the xml attribute android:gravity="center"

Comment: yes this is needed to position the text in the exact center.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In order for centering of hint text to work with EditText you have to make sure android:ellipsize="start" is defined. I don't know why this makes it work, but it does.

Example pulled from personal code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player2Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/player2_name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting and welcome to StackOverflow!  Yes, ellipsize="start" does affect this. Not sure why either. Without it the hint does not show for me.

Comment: I thinks i am too late here, but today i have seen this answer and reliazed that here is no need of android:ellipsize="start" in order to make a hint center,AFAIK. See my answer. May be it is also usefull.

Comment: As stated in other answers, it's android:gravity="center" (or a similar variant) that centers the text, not ellipsize.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? I suppose only `gravity` matters.

Comment: This could work by mistake in older Android, now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 42):

Actually, `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` creates the centering effect you're looking for. Similarly, you can use `android:gravity="start"` to put hint text at the beginning of the EditText view, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the `android:ellipsize="start"` and there was no change. Adding `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` did the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! the accepted answer is wrong!

Answer (score 36):

Use this xml attribute:

> android:gravity="center"

Comment: yes this is necessary to center the text.  vertically as well as horizontally.

Answer (score 11):

use attribute

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 8):

I used this code in every circumstances, and it works perfectly without using **android:ellipsize="start"** to make a hint in center.

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/player2Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="robi"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer should be :

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Comment: I agree, this is the correct answer to center the text only and not the hint.

Answer (score 5):

textAlignment worked for me.

```
textAlignment="center"
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, neither answer helped me aligning hint, written in LTR language, while the layout orientation was RTL. I needed such layout in a kind of translation application to make overlay icons not interfere with RTL text. But this trick didn't work with hints while there was no any text yet (icons appeared above the hint) and I came to the following java solution to layout problem:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
. . .
        if (isRightToLeft()){
            EditText guess = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            CharSequence hint = "\u200F" + guess.getHint();
            guess.setHint(hint);
        }
. . .
}
```

The trick was in right-to-left mark to prepend a left-to-right string. And it seems to work, but does anyone know a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="ENTER PIN"
            android:inputType="numberPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Note: in the tag TextInputEditText,the property

> android:gravity="center"

is what makes the deal of aligning the text in the center including the hint text

Answer (score 4):

use this: android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 4):

I use this and worked for me

```
android:gravity="Left|center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 3):

use   `android:textAlignment="center"` in EditText , it work for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nombreslayoutinput">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nombreslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/nombres"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"

        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal
```

Comment: Please read existing answers before contributing.  The accepted answer already has this portion of code in it.

Answer (score 1):

> hint gravity

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

> text gravity

```
android:gravity="left"
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the `EditText` wasn't big enought to fit exactly inside its parent (`FrameLayout` in my case), so using just `android:gravity="center"` (center_vertical, horizontal, start, or whatever) would just fit it inside the `EditText`, and not in its parent, so I had to center the `EditText` inside its parent using:

`android:layout_gravity="center"`

pd: I used  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to hide the ugly underline in the `EditText` hint