# EditText spacing looks odd

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I added an EditText to the layout, the layout contain this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_cause_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:hint="@string/cause_other_hint"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

and the result is this:
[image: EditText result]

1) the vertical space between the actual text (hint) to the line representing the EditText is to big (the vertical red line)

2) the horizontal space between the EditText border to the actual text (hint) is too small, should be idented a bit more.. (the horizontal red line)

How can I fix this to look nicer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303043/how-do-i-center-the-hint-text-within-and-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it by removing **android:padding="0dp"**. I got correct view.

Comment: This fixed only the 2nd part

Comment: He should also remove android:layout_weight="2" which seems useless here for his purpose.

Comment: Bush, you should also check out the link posted by Coder. One of the two answers there should help I think. I won't re-list them here to avoid duplication.

Comment: The layout_weight=2 is needed, but I wrapped the EditText with a LinearLayout and putted that there. Thanks