# How to change editText hint postion

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Can I change "hint" and text position (to rise it to the center)

[image]

My xml as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layoutTopBlue"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:background="#4285F4"
              android:layout_below="@id/layoutTopBlack"
        >
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text=''
            android:hint="my hint"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
            android:src="@drawable/cross"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or maybe it is possible to do something with drawable editText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@color/editBorder" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item android:bottom="1.5dp"
      android:left="1.5dp"
      android:right="1.5dp">
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@color/editBackground" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="5.0dp">
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@color/editBackground" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303043/how-do-i-center-the-hint-text-within-an-edittext-in-android

Comment: You can do it just by using android:gravity="center" attribute.

Comment: try to your EditText   `android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"`

Comment: centerInParent does not rise the hint, sorry

Comment: gravity should definitely work for you

Comment: gravity does not work too. I need to rise just hint

Comment: Maybe it is possible to move down the line?

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` should work. Else try `android:gravity="top"`. That will rise the text to top.

Comment: no. gravity does not work. Nor to top or center

Answer (score 4):

anyone can use

```
 android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical|top"
```

Comment: No, does not help. Maybe to change drawable somehow?

Answer (score 3):

**1) hind text in left of the edittext**

```
<EditText
     android:gravity="left"
/>
```

[image]

**2) hind text in center of the edittext**

```
<EditText
     android:gravity="center"
/>
```

[image]

**3) hind text in right of the edittext**

```
<EditText
     android:gravity="right"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: All above advices work with both hint/text and base editText line. I need to move up (rise) hint without touching the line below it. Maybe to make drawable editText invisible and to add another line? The question is how?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the position of edit text. 
In Graphical layout :- place the cursor in text(hint) and right click ,Layout height -> other -> then set the custom layout attribute value( example :50dp)
I think this will work .To rise it in center you can change this value to 30dp or 50dp.
                      or 
Change this line in Edit text :-

```
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="50dp"
```