# how to align the text(hint) in the center of edit text

Tags: android, android-layout

In this code although i have used text align attribute to set the "hint" in the center of the Edit Text view. But it is not working properly.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="Enter number here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center the hint text within an EditText in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303043/how-do-i-center-the-hint-text-within-an-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:gravity="center"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set Gravity to center.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="UserName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gravity with "center_horizontal" value or set padding top and padding bottom