# EditText hint is not centered

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I am using TextFieldInputLayout and Edittext field to design the following editText. according to the design collapsed view's hint top padding and text's bottom padding should be the same. But I am facing issue with that. Tried to add extra margin and padding, but couldn't find a proper solution. can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_last_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_with_gray_stroke"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_16dp"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/font_color_navy_blue"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_layout_first_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_last_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_12dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sfui_display_regular"
                android:hint="@string/last_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/font_color_navy_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: can you post you xml code?

possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303043/how-do-i-center-the-hint-text-within-an-edittext-in-android#:~:text=Actually%2C%20android%3Agravity%3D%22,EditText%20view%2C%20and%20so%20on.

Comment: I have added the code.  my issue is combining both hint and text in the center with equal top and bottom space.

Comment: can you try, adding `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"` at your `TextInputLayout`?

Comment: or try to change, `android:paddingTop` and `android:paddingBottom` with the same value?

Comment: i have tried those things. it is not visually centered.

Comment: better solution is, to make the defined size similar to each end, e.g. margin with it's top and bottom, padding with it's left and right...

Comment: also, i noticed that you are defining android:layout_height="70dp" at parent layout, which does not make sense, you may can adjust and put it on the TextInputEditText, and update TextInputLayout height with wrap_content

Comment: Try changing the layout height of the TextInputEditText view to "match_parent".